# How to detect which submit button was clicked when the names are unknown?

Tags: forms, jsp, submit

I know how to detect which submit button was clicked when I know the `name` values of each of the buttons. But what if the `name`s are dynamic or defined by another component?

For example, here I can simply check the POST data from this `<form>` for either `alpha` or `bravo`:

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" name="alpha" value="Alpha">
  <input type="submit" name="bravo" value="Bravo">
</form>
```

But that's only because I know I should be looking for those names.

Is there a best practice for handling this type of situation? (Perhaps by rendering an element `<input type="hidden" name="submit-button-names" value="dynamic_name1|dynamic_name2|etc">`.) I would like a solution that doesn't require JavaScript.

Comment: Every element should have an ID associated with it.

Comment: Right, but you can't get the `id` value from the POST data, can you? (I haven't coded in JSP myself before this.) Also, I still wouldn't know what `id` values to look for if they're dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have control over the JSP displaying these buttons, just prefix the button names with a string you can look for in the POSTed data. For example prepending "dynamicbutton_" to all of the names like this

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" name="dynamicbutton_alpha" value="Alpha">
  <input type="submit" name="dynamicbutton_bravo" value="Bravo">
</form>
```

Then in your Servlet, look for values with this prefix by calling [ServletRequest.getAttributeNames()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttributeNames%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom tag to set the different inputs to your form based on a list of parameters you give to the tag. 
   You would end up with the HTML looking something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="SelectColour.do">
    <p>Select your favorite colour: </p>
    <formTags:select name='colour' size='1' optionsList='${applicationScope.colourList}'/>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Click here to submit">
</form>
```

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31614/JSP-JSTL-Custom-Tag-Library) a decent guide to creating custom tags.